# What is the use of Following Redis Config entries

Tags: .net, redis

i am not getting Use of Following Redis Config entries.

key="RedisPoolSize" value="5"

key="RedisPoolTimeoutSeconds" value="1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is related to ServiceStack.Redis, even if it's not specified.

As ServiceStack.Redis does not provides any custom configuration section, it will do nothing without a little piece of code.

Besides, ServiceStack.Redis provides a PooledRedisClientManager, a manager that utilizes a pool of redis client connections. It's the typical connection pool pattern like for Sql Connections.

A connection pool is like a "cache" of connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when future requests to the redis db are required. Opening a connection for each request is costly, wastes resources and failry unefficient. That's we need a connection pool.

You give two common settings to configure a pool :

- RedisPoolSize : Number of client connections that should be keep in the pool
- RedisPoolTimeoutSeconds : Number of seconds to wait when trying to get a connection from the pool. Throw TimeoutException if timeout has expired.

Comment: What if I don't set values for keys. I mean what will be default values for them?

Comment: it's 2 secs for RedisPoolTimeout, and 10 for each read/write hosts